# MFMessageComposeViewController does not show message body

Tags: ios, swift, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have implemented the send message from my app using MFMessageComposeViewController.

When the app loads the message view controller I get only the message recipient and a cancel button and no message body or Send button.

I do add the message recipient and message body before initializing the MFMessageComposeViewController.

Now when I touch on the recipient list, then Message body and Send button pops up.

Can I ensure that the message body and Send button shows up at the same time as Message recipients and the cancel button.

The code is as follows:

Button on click of which action is triggered.

```
@IBAction func sendMessage(sender: AnyObject) {
    if (self.canSendText()) {
        let messageComposeVC = self.configuredMessageComposeViewController()
        presentViewController(messageComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        // Code to send error message
    }
}
```

Code to verify if message can be sent

```
func canSendText() -> Bool {
    return MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()
}
```

Code to compose the View Controller

```
func configuredMessageComposeViewController() -> MFMessageComposeViewController {
    let messageComposeVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    messageComposeVC.messageComposeDelegate = self  
    messageComposeVC.recipients = [SomeVariable]
    messageComposeVC.body = SomeText.text!
    return messageComposeVC
}
```

[Here is how it looks like when the MFMessageComposeViewcontroller looks like for the first time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjuAh.png)

Comment: Update your question with relevant code showing how you create, prepare, and display the message composer.

Comment: @rmaddy I have updated the code snippets. Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that `SomeText` and `SomeText.text` are not `nil`?

Comment: Yes. When I click on recipients, the Message body and Send button shows up which has the required text.

Comment: once check on real device

Comment: @ParvendraSingh I checked on real device only and it gives me that weird error. Let me know if I can try something else.

Answer (score 0):

So, I just deleted the whole thing and tried to create a new Scene and a new View controller from scratch. And it solved the problem. I ultimately used the same steps and same code as mentioned below in official Apple page.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/